# Подготовка данных для генератора

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

Я получаю значения из каталога

```
dateset = image_dataset_from_directory(
                            'Fruit-Images-Dataset-master/Training',
                            subset='training',
                            seed=42,
                            validation_split=0.1,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            image_size=image_size
)
```

И я хочу отправить на генератор и дискриминатор набор из вот таких данных

```
   [[image][tags][title]] 
   # image = [0.99607843, 1.         ,0.99215686, ...] 
   # tags = [Tomato, Tomato Cherry Red]
   # title = 1.png
```

Но проблема в том что я не понимаю как взаимодействовать с дата сетом

Я пытался каталогизировать изображения так

```
 Training
   Tomato
      Tomato 1
        1.png
          ...
       Tomato Cherry Red
         1.png
         2.png
            ...
```

Но в class_names выводит только Tomato а Tomato Cherry Red не видит

Как сделать так что бы метки было больше чем одна?

Я пытался пройтись по каждому элементу отдельно

```
SIZE = 224
def resize_image(img, label):
  img = img.numpy().astype("uint8")
  img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)
  img = tf.image.resize(img, (SIZE, SIZE)) # изменить размер
  img = img / 255.0 # Перемножить значение что бы оно было равно 0. или 1.
  img = np.concatenate(myimg, axis=1) # Соединить 3 цвета в одну строку 
  return img, label
train_resized = training_dateset[0].map(resize_image) # Преобразовать
```

Но получил

```
 'PrefetchDataset' object is not subscriptable?
```

Как мне правильно подготовить данные(Редактировать их)? Что бы их структура была примерно такой

```
  [
    [[image][tags][title]],
    [[image][tags][title]],
    [[image][tags][title]]
  ]
```

Comment: Зачем вы одно и то же в разных вопросах спрашивайте? Лучше бы дополняли свой предыдущий вопрос.

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну мне казалось это слегка разные вопросы. В прошлом я спрашивал про ошибку `PrefetchDataset` А здесь спрашиваю как лучше всего подготовить данные в нужном мне формате. Где конструкция `map` вообще может быть не задействована.

Comment: Ну ок, хотя ошибку вы приводите ту же самую )